# Binary Search RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-search, recursionerror

I was trying to execute the Binary Search program in python. I followed the algorithm steps yet it gives me this error. Here's my code:

```
def binarySearch(a,k,l,r):
    
    if l > r:
        return -1
    else:
        mid = (l+(r-l))//2
        if(a[mid]>k):
            return binarySearch(a,k,l,mid-1)
        elif(a[mid]<k):
            return binarySearch(a,k,mid+1,r)
        else:
            return mid


t = int(input("Enter no. of test cases: "))
for _ in range(t):
    n,k = map(int, input().split())
    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    print(binarySearch(a,k,0,n))
```

Error:

```
    return binarySearch(a,k,mid+1,r)
  File "e:/Coding/Algorithms/Searching/binarySearch.py", line 10, in binarySearch
    return binarySearch(a,k,mid+1,r)
  File "e:/Coding/Algorithms/Searching/binarySearch.py", line 10, in binarySearch
    return binarySearch(a,k,mid+1,r)  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
  File "e:/Coding/Algorithms/Searching/binarySearch.py", line 3, in binarySearch    if r < l:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error lies in this line:

```py
    else:
        mid = (l+(r-l))//2
```

You need to divide `(r-l)//2` and then add `l` but you are doing `(l+(r-l))//2` which results in `(l+r-l)//2 == r//2`.

Change it to `l + (r-l)//2`.

What happens is when this condition is true:

```py
        elif(a[mid]<k):
            return binarySearch(a,k,mid+1,r)
```

`r` stays the same and since you are always dividing `r` without considering `l`, `mid` never changes. So, you get a recursion depth exceeded error.

Also, the upper bound of the search is `n-1` where `n` is the length of the array. If the `n` in your function call is the length of the array (it isn't obvious from the code), you need to subtract one as follows:

```py
binarySearch(a,k,0,n-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the item isn't found in the list, the recursion never converges. There are two mistakes here:

1. `r`'s starting value should be `n-1`, not `n`
2. The calculation of `mid` should not subtract `1`. I.e., it should be `mid = (l+r)//2`.

Put these together and you'll get:

```py
def binarySearch(a,k,l,r):

    if l > r:
        return -1
    else:
        mid = (l+r)//2
        if(a[mid]>k):
            return binarySearch(a,k,l,mid-1)
        elif(a[mid]<k):
            return binarySearch(a,k,mid+1,r)
        else:
            return mid
```